# Script test to see if a tool is already loaded?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, centos

I'm learning docker, and I was trying to do shell test to see if key tools are already loaded. I'm doing some tests on deploying docker to different flavors of servers.  Here is the script, saved as dockerScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
## run "$  chmod +x dockerScript.sh" to make the script executable.
## then run "./dockerScript.sh" to activate the script 
touch docker-compose.yml
cat > docker-compose.yml <<EOL
version: "2"
services:
    (etc...)
EOL
if[docker-compose is not already loaded] <--- what goes here?
then
    curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.14.0-rc2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
fi

docker-compose up -d
```

In this case, I'd like to verify that `docker-compose` is loaded.  I'm not quite sure exactly how to do that.

I see that if I `$ docker-compose -v` I get a response like

`docker-compose version 1.14.0-rc2, build 24dae73` for success

and either

`-bash: docker-compose: command not found` or

`bash: docker-compose: command not found`

as a response if the tool is not loaded depending on exactly which flavor of linux I'd be using.

Is there a way to test the operating system for the presence / installation of the `docker-compose` tool and complete my shell script?

Comment: Does `if docker-compose -v >/dev/null;then` not work?

Comment: Nope. That was a reply to someone else who suggested using a `which` test.

Comment: `pgrep docker-compose`? (Do I understand 'loaded' right?)

Comment: @123 No luck.  That if (/dev/null) test fails as written.  When I do `$ which docker-compose` is see a response of `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose`, but it not clear if that is true for all installations.

Comment: @hidefromkgb That looks good but seems to fail. `# pgrep docker-compose -c` --> `0` and `# docker-compose -v` -->  `docker-compose version 1.14.0-rc2, build 24dae73`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hash` command

```
hash docker-compose 2>/dev/null || { echo >&2 "I require docker-compose but it's not installed."; }
```

> `hash` is a bash built-in command. The hash table is a feature of bash that prevents it from having to search `$PATH` every time you type a command by caching the results in memory.

You can use `hash` command and don't worry has installed `hash` utillity on your system or not. If you have `bash` then you have `hash`.

`hash some_cmd 2>/dev/null` means redirect error output from stderr to /dev/null

Comment: I'm lost.  Can you explain what exactly is going on here?  Hash appears to be a tool that 'remembers' previous shell commands.  I'm trying out a whole bunch of pre-canned OS systems.  If tools were installed at a virgin OS build, would `hash` have a record of that?  Or does hash just remember things I've typed?  What's the `2>` symbol? etc... This may well be the right answer, but without explanation it has little staying power and value to others in the future.

Comment: Sorry, i will try to explain my answer

Comment: Many thanks... that seems to be working for me.  and yeah, I'm still learning the ins and outs of shell scripts, too.